# System.ArgumentException: Handle must be valid. in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Occasionaly I get this exception in my Xamarin Android app:

```
Message: , ExceptionText: System.ArgumentException: Handle must be valid.
Parameter name: instance
at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/b16fb820/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11271 
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/b16fb820/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/JNIEnv.g.cs:102 
at Android.Support.V4.Util.LruCache.Get (Java.Lang.Object key) [0x00051] in <6b598472177d41bdb28b48b89f407895>:0 
at MyApp.ClientApp.Droid.Views.Adapters.CachingImagesAdapter`1[T].OnBindBasicViewHolder (Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView+ViewHolder holder, System.Int32 position) [0x00085] in C:\Projects\MyAppForClients.Droid\MyApp.ClientApp\Views\Adapters\CachingImagesAdapter.cs:247
```

In my case object which throws the exception is an instance of `LruCache` declared as private member of a derivative of `RecyclerView.Adapter`. This adapter is a private member of `Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatDialogFragment` derivative. And the fragments are added to the `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentPagerAdapter`.

I call `LruCache.Get` in `OnResume` and the exception appears on the n-th time of putting the app into background and back to the foreground again which triggers `OnResume`.

Google does not have much to say on this problem. I've found a similar problem  [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=47577#c3), but there is no answer. Other developers in my team have also stated that this problem sometimes occurs in their Xamarin apps, like in this case:

```
Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniMethodInfo method)<c16d37a6da97402f84017e03c10d21d0>:0
Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod)<d23d7850e6494c6fb18444fff8001568>:0
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.get_Resources()<6296d3d76c5d4378959a1d9bf7205023>
```

Can I do anything to stop this from happening?

Comment: Have you tried setting the GC bridge to `old` (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=47577#c3)?

Comment: I haven't, but I will now, tnx

Comment: If that does work, creating a test case that repos the issue and attaching to that bug report would help the Xamarin team in tracing the issue.

Comment: @SushiHangover, I've tried setting 'MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=old' and now I don't get this exception anymore. But as I said, it's not 100% reproducible bug so I will spend more time testing until I can say the problem has been solved. Thank you!